# SQLSTATE[42000] on the Haversine formula in PHP/MySQL and CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, haversine, geopoints

I am just testing the Haversine formula taking from Google Developers: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

I've put the snippet into my code and it gives me a SQL error.

This is my Model in CakePHP:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class LocationModel extends Model {

    public $name = 'Location';

    public function getNearest()
    {
        $this->Location->query("SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";);
    }   
}
```

I've literally copied and pasted the code and put it into the query function. I don't think it's anything to do with my database or anything but rather a syntax error in SQL but I can't see it. What is wrong with it?

This is the error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getNearest' at line 1
```

Comment: You sure what you have pasted above is what you ran when you got that error? It looks like MySQL is complaining about there not being a function called `getNearest` defined. Somehow `getNearest` got into the query you executed...

Comment: Yeah it is, the only place getNearest() is called is in my LocationsController where I call it like this: 

$this->loadModel("Location");
$this->set("locations", $this->Location->getNearest());

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like the query that's running is just "getNearest()" which, if I run it against my test MySQL instance, produces this familiar error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getNearest()' at line 1`. Somehow your query is becoming polluted...weird. Does Cake automatically execute `$this->Location->getNearest` as a SQL query maybe?